# Elegant to call all Spring Cloud Service instance one bye one

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Assume we have eureka-server A, eureka-client B (with three instances B1 B2 B3) and C(C1)

Now I want to do this:
C1 invoke each B instance once with URL like B/test, is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject in your app EurekaClient ant try to get all instances:

```
@Autowired
private EurekaClient eurekaClient;

public void getAllInstance(){
    eurekaClient.getApplication("B-service").getInstances();
    ...
}
```

now you need to send your request to the each instance